# Do I also need to upgrade to TFS 2010 RC?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm currently using the beta2 versions VS2010 Ultimate and TFS. I want to upgrade to the VS to the RC release, and I dont mind that, not much trouble. However, Do I need to install the TFS again for it to work? Because that would probably wouldn't be as smooth as just VS...

Comment: VS 2010 works well with TFS 2008. I know that doesn't answer your question, but at least it gives you another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TFS 2010 beta2 is no longer supported with VS2010RC.

I updated from the B2 to the RC and it was dead simple.  I upgraded in place with no side effects.  It took me about 30 minutes (excluding backing up my VM).

Comment: +! for making a backup beforehand. You never know what might happen during the upgrade process.